# leaflet Map get greyed out when changing the centre

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet

I have have a list of latlng clicking on which the map centre is set with that latlng. the issue occurs when I switch between the latlng the map is getting greyed out.

I have tried:-

1. Changing the leaflet map version
2. Using InvalidateSize function
3. Use panTo, flyTo instead of setView
4. Used leaflet internal reset function

Here is an plunker demo for the issue, Switch between location1 and location2 for 3-4 times.
https://plnkr.co/edit/87cFuRJ7iBKn1cTeVPb9?p=preview

```js
// Code goes here


setTimeout(() => {
  tiles = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({
    maxZoom: 20,
    type: 'roadmap',
    streetViewControl: true,
    continuousWorld: false
  });
  latlng = L.latLng(30.695267, 76.879746);
  displayedMap = L.map('map_canvas', {
    center: latlng,
    zoom: 13,
    layers: [tiles],
    fullscreenControl: {
      pseudoFullscreen: false // if true, fullscreen to page width and height
    },
    customControl: '<map-control/>',
    attributionControl: false,
    maxBoundsViscosity: 0.75,
    minZoom: 2,
    worldCopyJump: true,
    zoomControl: true,
    streetViewControl: true,
    streetViewControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    options: {},
    ourCustomControl: function(template) {}
  });

  L.DomEvent.on(document.getElementById('loc1'), 'click', function() {
    console.log('loc1 click')
    displayedMap.setView(L.latLng(30.695267, 76.879746), 13)
  })
  L.DomEvent.on(document.getElementById('loc2'), 'click', function() {
    console.log('loc2 click')
    displayedMap.setView(L.latLng(30.799228, 76.914633), 13)
  })
}, 200)
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" async defer></script>
<!--<script src="leaflet.js"></script>-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet-src.js" integrity="sha512-+ZaXMZ7sjFMiCigvm8WjllFy6g3aou3+GZngAtugLzrmPFKFK7yjSri0XnElvCTu/PrifAYQuxZTybAEkA8VOA==" crossorigin=""></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant@0.8.0/Leaflet.GoogleMutant.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==" crossorigin="" />

<style>
  #map_canvas {
    width: 50vw;
    height: 50vh;
  }
</style>

<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<button id="loc1" type="button">location1</button>
<button id="loc2" type="button">location2</button>
```

Comment: The way you create the map (with settimeout ) is quite strange to me.
the solution given works, but you can try to use a more practical way to load the map (document.ready for example)

Answer (score 1):

I realized that zooming fixes problem. You can write your click functions as follow.

```
L.DomEvent.on(document.getElementById('loc1'), 'click', function(){
  console.log('loc1 click');
  displayedMap.setView(L.latLng(30.695267, 76.879746),12);
  displayedMap.zoomIn(1);
})
L.DomEvent.on(document.getElementById('loc2'), 'click', function(){
  console.log('loc2 click');
  displayedMap.setView(L.latLng(30.799228, 76.914633),12);
  displayedMap.zoomIn(1);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this did't fix the issue.